# Passing a string to Function.prototype.apply() JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

I currently have a need to have a set of function arguments defined as a comma separated string and passed in at a later time.

I would like my code to function somewhat as follows.

```
function bar() {
    console.log("My name is " + arguments[0].name + " and my species is " arguments[0].species);
    console.log("String 1: " + arguments[1]);
    console.log("String 2: " + arguments[2]);
}

function foo() {
    var args = "{name: 'Dean Brunt', species: 'Human'}, 'A string', 'Some other input string, oh yes'";
    bar.apply(null, args);
}
```

I would like this to produce the output to the console:

```
My name is Dean Brunt and my species is Human
String 1: A string
String 2: Some other input string, oh yes
```

However, this does not work as `Function.prototype.apply()` takes an array as its' second argument. Whilst, I have tried converting the args string to an array, I have struggled with this due to the non-trivial regex split this would incur and my attempts have been fruitless.

Could anyone help me define an appropriate regex object I could use for the split or suggest an alternative that would produce the same result.

Many thanks.

Comment: what is var args?  it'll throw a syntax error as is, with double quotes inside double quotes.  once that's a valid object/string you can wrap it with brackets to make it a 1-element array and all should be good.

Comment: @James that was a typo on my part. args should be a string that represents a set of comma seperated values that would be passed as arguments to a function. Also, for this reason, I can't see how wrapping it as a 1-element array would work as then surely `apply` would consider the singular element as the only function argument, rather than 3 seperate arguments as I desire.

Comment: Where is args coming from? Why is it a string?

Comment: @melpomene args is pulled from a data attribute on a HTML element. The specification I have dictates that the attribute contains comma separated values that are to be passed to pre-defined functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not pretty, but you can use `eval`:

```js
function bar() {
    console.log("My name is " + arguments[0].name + " and my species is " + arguments[0].species);
    console.log("String 1: " + arguments[1]);
    console.log("String 2: " + arguments[2]);
}

function foo() {
    var args = "{name: 'Dean Brunt', species: 'Human'}, 'A string', 'Some other input string, oh yes'";
    bar.apply(null, eval('[' + args + ']'));
}

foo();
```

Comment: Excellent, this does do what I need, even if not pretty. I completely forgot of eval's existence. Many thanks.

Comment: You could use JSON.parse instead of eval.

Answer (score 0):

You can use eval().
Writing a regex would be quite tedious.

```
function stringToArgs(str){
   return eval(`(function(){return arguments;})(${str})`);
}

function bar(arguments) {
    console.log("My name is " + arguments[0].name + " and my species is " +arguments[0].species);
    console.log("String 1: " + arguments[1]);
    console.log("String 2: " + arguments[2]);
}

function foo() {
    var args = "{name: 'Dean Brunt', species: 'Human'}, 'A string', 'Some other input string, oh yes'";
    bar(stringToArgs(args));
}

foo();
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not fool-proof, but it's a start.

You should begin by formatting your data to *look like* JSON, then parse it. This is the easiest way.

```js
function printInfo() {
  console.log("My name is " + arguments[0].name + " and my species is " + arguments[0].species);
  console.log("String 1: " + arguments[1]);
  console.log("String 2: " + arguments[2]);
}

function parseInfo() {
  var jsonStr = '[' + repairJson(arguments[0]) + ']';
  var jsonObj = JSON.parse(jsonStr);
  printInfo.apply(null, jsonObj);
}

// Add and repair quotes.
function repairJson(str) {
  return str.replace(/[']/g, '"').replace(/(\b\w+\b):/g, '"$1":');
}

parseInfo("{name: 'Dean Brunt', species: 'Human'}, 'A string', 'Some other input string, oh yes'");
```

---

#### Bonus

This is a little outside of the scope of what you're asking, but it's the best way, if you can actually modify your data.

```js
class Animal {
  constructor(name, species) {
    this.name = name;
    this.species = species;
  }
  toString() {
    return `My name is ${this.name} and my species is ${this.species}.`;
  }
}

function print() {
  console.log([].slice.apply(arguments).join(' '));
}

function printEach() {
  [].slice.apply(arguments).forEach(arg => console.log(arg));
}

print(new Animal('Dean Brunt', 'Human'), 'A string', 'Some other input string, oh yes');
```